# "pdfTeX error: cannot open Type 1 font" problem while loading Arabic script on LyX

Tags: arabic, pdflatex, tex, lyx

When I do an attempt to exporting to PDF a document with Arabic text on LyX using pdfTeX engine, appear an error like this.

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ae_almohanad_bold.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font f
```

My logs from my LaTeX logs are this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.7.25)  26 JUL 2023 19:44
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./tes_bahasa_arab-2.tex
(tes_bahasa_arab-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>

(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/laeenc.def
File: laeenc.def 2006/01/01 v0.1 Local Arabic font encoding (test version: may 
change)
Now handling font encoding LAE ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LAE
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/laeenc.dfu
File: laeenc.dfu 2006/01/01 v1.0 UTF-8 support for Arabic and Farsi for use wit
h inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+066A (decimal 1642)
   defining Unicode char U+060C (decimal 1548)
   defining Unicode char U+0660 (decimal 1632)
   defining Unicode char U+0661 (decimal 1633)
   defining Unicode char U+0662 (decimal 1634)
   defining Unicode char U+0663 (decimal 1635)
   defining Unicode char U+0664 (decimal 1636)
   defining Unicode char U+0665 (decimal 1637)
   defining Unicode char U+0666 (decimal 1638)
   defining Unicode char U+0667 (decimal 1639)
   defining Unicode char U+0668 (decimal 1640)
   defining Unicode char U+0669 (decimal 1641)
   defining Unicode char U+061B (decimal 1563)
   defining Unicode char U+061F (decimal 1567)
   defining Unicode char U+0621 (decimal 1569)
   defining Unicode char U+0622 (decimal 1570)
   defining Unicode char U+0623 (decimal 1571)
   defining Unicode char U+0624 (decimal 1572)
   defining Unicode char U+0625 (decimal 1573)
   defining Unicode char U+0626 (decimal 1574)
   defining Unicode char U+0627 (decimal 1575)
   defining Unicode char U+0628 (decimal 1576)
   defining Unicode char U+0629 (decimal 1577)
   defining Unicode char U+062A (decimal 1578)
   defining Unicode char U+062B (decimal 1579)
   defining Unicode char U+062C (decimal 1580)
   defining Unicode char U+062D (decimal 1581)
   defining Unicode char U+062E (decimal 1582)
   defining Unicode char U+062F (decimal 1583)
   defining Unicode char U+0630 (decimal 1584)
   defining Unicode char U+0631 (decimal 1585)
   defining Unicode char U+0632 (decimal 1586)
   defining Unicode char U+0633 (decimal 1587)
   defining Unicode char U+0634 (decimal 1588)
   defining Unicode char U+0635 (decimal 1589)
   defining Unicode char U+0636 (decimal 1590)
   defining Unicode char U+0637 (decimal 1591)
   defining Unicode char U+0638 (decimal 1592)
   defining Unicode char U+0639 (decimal 1593)
   defining Unicode char U+063A (decimal 1594)
   defining Unicode char U+0640 (decimal 1600)
   defining Unicode char U+0641 (decimal 1601)
   defining Unicode char U+0642 (decimal 1602)
   defining Unicode char U+0643 (decimal 1603)
   defining Unicode char U+0644 (decimal 1604)
   defining Unicode char U+0645 (decimal 1605)
   defining Unicode char U+0646 (decimal 1606)
   defining Unicode char U+0647 (decimal 1607)
   defining Unicode char U+0648 (decimal 1608)
   defining Unicode char U+0649 (decimal 1609)
   defining Unicode char U+064A (decimal 1610)
   defining Unicode char U+064B (decimal 1611)
   defining Unicode char U+064C (decimal 1612)
   defining Unicode char U+064D (decimal 1613)
   defining Unicode char U+064E (decimal 1614)
   defining Unicode char U+064F (decimal 1615)
   defining Unicode char U+0650 (decimal 1616)
   defining Unicode char U+0651 (decimal 1617)
   defining Unicode char U+0652 (decimal 1618)
   defining Unicode char U+067E (decimal 1662)
   defining Unicode char U+0686 (decimal 1670)
   defining Unicode char U+0698 (decimal 1688)
   defining Unicode char U+06A9 (decimal 1705)
   defining Unicode char U+06AF (decimal 1711)
   defining Unicode char U+06CC (decimal 1740)
   defining Unicode char U+06F0 (decimal 1776)
   defining Unicode char U+06F1 (decimal 1777)
   defining Unicode char U+06F2 (decimal 1778)
   defining Unicode char U+06F3 (decimal 1779)
   defining Unicode char U+06F4 (decimal 1780)
   defining Unicode char U+06F5 (decimal 1781)
   defining Unicode char U+06F6 (decimal 1782)
   defining Unicode char U+06F7 (decimal 1783)
   defining Unicode char U+06F8 (decimal 1784)
   defining Unicode char U+06F9 (decimal 1785)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+06D5 (decimal 1749)
))) (/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/cp1256.def
File: cp1256.def 2006/01/01 v0.1 CP1256 Arabic input encoding file
) (/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
)) (/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2023/06/26 v3.90 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count193
\U@D=\dimen141
\l@unhyphenated=\language1
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count194
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
) (/home/hikam/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/arabic.ldf
File: arabic.ldf 
Language: arabic 2006/01/01 v0.1 Arabic support for the babel system

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language 'Arabic' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 35.

...

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ae_almohanad_bold.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font f
ile for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What's the problem and how to fix it?. Even, I use full package of TeXLive or `texlive-full` now in my Xubuntu 22.04 computer. I currently use LyX version 2.3.6.

I was copied a folder containing all fonts needed for Arabic text rendering with TeX. Just to know that I use `arabi` for rendering my Arabic text on LyX.

I took the `arabi` files from CTAN to my Download (Unduhan) folder inside my home directory and I copied the Type 1 font folder inside that (`/home/hikam/Unduhan/arabi/arabi/texmf/fonts/type1/arabi/`) to directory `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/`. Even this doesn't fix the problem I mention before.

Need to know that ae_almohanad_bold.pfb is located inside my downloaded `arabi` folder that I copied to texmf directory.

Comment: I try that.....

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when adding a phrase in Arabic with arabi and using MikTex. The solution for me (more like a workaround, really) was adding the `ae_almohanad_bold.pfb` file from the [package in ctan](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/fonts/type1/arabi/arabeyes) directly to my project directory.

A real fix would be properly adding this file (and likely all related ones) to the package in MikTex, but I don't know how to do that.